# Ubuntu Installation: USB drive is not available under "Device for boot loader installation" dropdown

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive

### TLDR;

I Booted from an Ubuntu USB. During the installation from the USB into the Harddisk, USB Drive is not available as a source.

### Background

I have an old PC with 4 GB RAM running on Windows 10. I decided to replace Windows with Ubuntu 22.04 (Not Dual Boot).

1. I made a bootable USB Drive with Ubuntu ISO using Rufus.
2. I changed the boot order from BIOS.
3. I booted my PC with Ubuntu from the USB Drive (`/dev/sdb` 57.73.GiB)
4. I clicked on the "Try Ubuntu"
5. I tried installing Ubuntu without any swap area on the hard drive

The task **ran for about 11 hours**, and suddenly we faced an electricity failure.

After that, I tried again, and this time I made a swap partition

[image: Partition]

But as you can see the Hard Drive itself is solely visible on the "Device for boot loader installation" dropdown. I tried moving top-bottom, but the second item is **`/dev/sda1` Windows 10**, the third is `/dev/sda2`, and so on and so forth. I found no `/dev/sdb` under the dropdown - all are `/dev/sda$`.

[image: GParted]

The issue is if I choose the `/dev/sda` (1TB) Hard Drive (as I am bound to do so), the installation says: it found a half-done partition, whether I can continue or go back. If I can't react in a hurry, I simply stuck to the Window, and can't rescue until I restart the system. If I could click the "Continue" button in a hurry, then the system simply says:

> "Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #2 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda)...

...with a completely filled progress bar with no hint of completing the task, and run for hours after hours with no result.

[image: Installtion]

The terminal below the window simply shows if I perform any task on this Ubuntu Instance, eg. disconnecting the internet, opening the browser, closing the browser, etc., and doesn't show any progress on the partition itself.

**How can I install Ubuntu to an HDD from a USB Drive?**

Comment: The one step I see you missing is where you verified the ISO. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview It may be corrupt.

Comment: And if you want Ubuntu only then choose "erase and install", nothing else to configure..

Comment: The bootloader should always go to the internal drive, and you should choose the whole drive `/dev/sda` in this case as shown in the picture. **Adding the bootloader to the USB installation drive will not work!** Don't use "Something Else". Use the default installation process to erase and install. Don't worry about swap or no swap. **Note: Erase and install will delete everything in the HDD that includes Windows and all your documents, pictures, music, videos, and whatever else you have inside the computer.**

Comment: Opinion:  I've found some releases easier to install to external drives than others, and it's almost impossible on some devices but easy with the same release on other hardware; ie. your machine firmware seems to matter. If it's difficult on one device; I've resorted to install on another ~like device (*with its different firmware*) then used the external drive on the device I had issues with; adjusting it's boot config so it'll boot from the prepared external drive. ie. the Ubuntu software operation cannot overrule your machine's firmware